# Find the spectrum of graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Find the spectrum for the following graph by calcuation

[image]

> The spectrum of a graph $G$ is a list of the eigenvalues and the multiplicities of the eigenvalues of the adjacency of matrix $A$ of $G$. I found the adjacency matrix of $G$ as $x^5 -7x^3 -4x^2+2x$. I am stack to find the eigenvalues and the multiplicities. I would like to get a seed of an idea, how can I do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can label each vertex $V= \{v_1,\cdots,v_6\}$ and then create the adjacency matrix 
$$A_{i,j}=\left\{\begin{array}{rl} 1 & v_i \text{ and } v_j \text{ share an edge} \\
0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{array}\right.$$
Then find the eigenvalues of $A$ computationally using Mathematica, WolframAlpha, or Matlab (or any other program you'd like).